# MD5 for entire asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Is there any sort of MD5 hash or cache key generated by the asset-pipeline that represents all the files in the assets folder? I'm looking for a way to know when assets have been added, removed, or updated between deploys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such cache with a single hash of all assets. On production, if you precompiled your assets, you should find a [sprockets manifest file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) in the public assets directory (usually something like `.sprockets-manifest-*randomnumber*.json`), but this file contains hashes for all individual assets. So, you'd have to compare all the hashes to know a difference.

If all you wanted is actually to speed up deploys, take a look at the [capistrano-faster-assets gem](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-faster-assets) which does just that - it compares the assets from the current deployment with the assets of the previous deployment. If there is no difference, it skips assets precompilation which greatly saves time during deploys. This gem uses the `diff` unix command to compare the asset directories. You can take a look in the [comparison task source code](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-faster-assets/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/faster_assets.rake) for inspiration if you need to do something else than the gem.